# Flash: `sprite.visible = false` doesn't hide sprite immediately?

Tags: flash

I've got a sprite which I want to temporarily hide… But changing the `.visible` property doesn't do what I expect. The code looks roughly like this:

```
childLayer.visible = false;
onLoadComplete(function():void {
    childLayer.visible = true;
});
```

But the `childLayer` isn't being hidden right away (in fact, it doesn't appear to be hidden at all unless I remove the `childLayer.visible = true`, in which case it does eventually hide).

However, if I remove the `childLayer` from the parent, everything works just like I would expect:

```
parentLayer.removeChild(childLayer);
onLoadComplete(function():void {
    parentLayer.addChild(childLayer);
});
```

Why would removing the child work when setting `.visible = false` “not work”?

**Edit**: turns out I'm just an idiot. Some other component was setting `childLayer.visible = true` before the `onLoadComplete` callback was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey David, hard to say without seeing more code. One thing I know can cause issues is using cacheAsBitmap, is that set anywhere on the display list above this object? If set, it might not be refreshing correctly. It should work immediately (next render loop).

What does onLoadComplete look like?

Comment: Basically this code executes when loading new data… `onLoadComplete` just calls the function once all the data is loaded and ready to go.

It's possible that something has `cacheAsBitmap` set. I'll check on that. Thanks.

Comment: No, `cacheAsBitmap` is not being set anywhere above the object (although it is being set for the children of some of its siblings).

Comment: Oh, wait, it turns out I'm just an idiot. Some code, somewhere, was changing `.visible` to `true`.

Comment: Just want to add to this a little bit, one way to force visibility or redraw-based-changes to take effect immediately is to call the invalidate method on stage. stage.invalidate(); will force a redraw immediately.